# Degree of Johnson graphs and their subgraphs

Tags: graph-theory

What is the degree of Johnson graph $J(n,k)$ where $n>k$?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson_graph

What are some good examples of subgraphs of Johnson graphs? The Johnson graph I am interested in is $J(n,2)$.

Comment: Hi JAS! This community values questions where askers show their thoughts on the problem in their posts. Displaying your ideas and past work allows us to see the level at which you are working and the concepts which you have (or not) encountered. That way, the information we give can be best suited to you, and answerers can help many people. I decided to overlook it because you're not exactly a new user and you seem to know how to write questions, but when you posted the second question, posed without work in a terse tone, I felt like a reminder could help keep frustrations down in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Wikipedia page: Johnson graphs have ${n \choose k}$ vertices and $\frac{k(n-k)}{2}{n \choose k}$ edges. So there is a natural number to try.

Comment: I already upvoted your answer. Your answer helped me use the data I overlooked.

Comment: @JAS: And I appreciate it, but my complaint isn't about upvotes or reputation. Sorry. I'm asking you to be more considerate that answerers on this site are here as volunteers. If you think I'm being unreasonable I guess you can take it back.

Comment: Do you want me to make the subgraphs of Johnson graphs as different question?

Comment: @JAS: Not really. If you are interested in improving this post (specifically that question in it), then it would be nice to know why you are interested in Johnson graphs, and what sort of examples of subgraphs might be considered "good".